# How to achieve this image effect in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to add shadow effect like one shown in the below screenshot.

How can I achieve this in Flutter ?

[image: Profile Picture effect]

Comment: What effect are you talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `drop_shadow_image` package on pub.dev.

[drop_shadow_image](https://pub.dev/packages/drop_shadow_image).

### You can check out the example below:

#### Install:

```dart
import 'package:drop_shadow_image/drop_shadow_image.dart';
```

#### Use:

```dart
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:drop_shadow_image/drop_shadow_lib.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body:
        Center(
          child: DropShadowImage(
            offset: Offset(10,10),
            scale: 1,
            blurRadius: 12,
            borderRadius: 20,
            image: Image.asset('assets/cat.png',
            width: 300,),
          ),
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In image its not clear which effect you want but i assume that you want that shadow effect.

If is that's so then the below answer will work for you.

You can easily achieve this in flutter using Container's decoration **boxShadow** attribute.

In flutter create a container and do like this:-

```
Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  offset: Offset(20,20), // The alignment of the effect(x,y)
                  spreadRadius: 1, //Spread radius means how much it will spread
                  blurRadius: 14, //How big the blus will be
                  color: Color(0xFF000000) //color of the effect.
                )
              ]
            ),
           ),
```

and then attach the Image as a child of the container.

Also if you want to have the round corners in the image wrap the Image inside ClipRRect widget.
Here's how to do this:-

```
ClipRRect(
          child: Image.asset('assets/img/1.png'),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60), //radius of the corner adjusting this will give you rounded corner.
          ),
```

Putting things together: -

```
Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  offset: Offset(20,20), // The alignment of the effect(x,y)
                  spreadRadius: 1, //Spread radius means how much it will spread
                  blurRadius: 14, //How big the blus will be
                  color: Color(0xFF000000) //color of the effect.
                )
              ]
            ),
              child: `ClipRRect(
                     child: Image.asset('assets/img/1.png'),
                     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60), //radius of the corner adjusting this will give you rounded corner.
          ),`
         ),
```

Hope this solves your problem.

~~Happy coding...